# Client side convert png file stream into file object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, axios

I get 'png image stream' from an API.The API uses gm(GraphicsMagick) to generate image file stream.

In client side I am using axios to make API call. Successfully I am able to receive the response.In client side I have to convert this file stream into a file object.

I use the below code for that. But it didn't help to get the actual image back.  Help me to convert the file stream into a valid image file object in client side

Code:

```
const imageStream = response.data;
const blob = new Blob([imageStream], { type: 'image/png' });
const imageFile = new File([blob], 'file1.png', { type: 'image/png' })
```

API Response

```
Response Header:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Image-Validation-Results
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:75192
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Fri, 26 Jan 2018 21:56:05 GMT
```

`Response`

```
PNG


IHDRÈÈ":9ÉgAMA±üasRGB®Îé cHRMz&úèu0ê`:pºQ<bKGDÿÿÿ ½§    pHYsÒÝ~üIDATxÚìýTTÙî.ªÈÌmïî¶vÖN¶­Ýæ,
æÅsÎY1cF@$ç¡*VÎIw®l÷¾÷ñî;ç¼ö±sÔX,*¨ú­ïûþÿ9×*¨ã¿_ÿýú?ðý÷%øï×Áúï×Áúï×Áúï×?øÕþêhÿÏÑÖÞþ÷hkoý9Àoý¬×æÝ}e´µÿÏFk×øzSÛ»Æ«d´··ÿêåøßý¯¿°­­ýÿçA¯÷í8nÿ7}ý­ÿÿSÿWkG½£ÃF{¥­¶µS¶vÜÒfä[5]IÚUT¯DØjV¥ÀªXA½!»¦9«JY©J+U>/P?ÉVÝMÝz!»ßpáiÝÇójNß¯:z»ìðÍâó÷óKªkÛÚ¬Ý   ÄÿÿXàØmùnûûHý·÷÷5@¶Í1À»kiï0µwpíl{ÝÚÁ´u0­¸­ÃhíÐ;øö¶£î¨¡Ú«ÈV0ÊÐL=CgKk¶>R6î7pwëØ:º¾RÅ)$æ{ó°¨TxCa}¢~u~i¬vM¬zþCeðíÆé7¥S¯ÕO¿T7åBõÔóSÏWN:Y>ñxñØ£cÜ3rOæè]i#·'Üø×çlJ?lCüÏkc\ýtÈª'CV<üsÍ½àm'Ãwí»w÷Â};ìÙ2o÷ú¹;ÖnÙµeÆºmAkvNZ½'hÃÍg\K*V#ÄËÿ^ÐÓÿóoô¿¬´í­­mÝ"ÿÿîÝmië°·µÛ[Û[ZÛí-m--í`Øím@º[Z[lv['¢&³a³3YÂp 8gF\o@a=fP#Í*X§ur£º^'¯VËªò
¥¬TÞ×X%mÈ¬§ÕÉjUÖ?©>ªl)k¼[\{­@r>¿þbäldzÅÞä=Iå[oO(Ûþ¢d{bÙæøÒõ±%ëlzZ´éqþ¦ÇQò×ÞÏ_{7{õÌ%7Ò\Ë¿~1#ürFÄy×rçÛË¹ó/çÎ»»àbÞKù.åÍ¿»ð"Ø·àbáÂ/æ/¼P¸l/w¾`îÂy*æ+
?]<çtYèé² ÁÇË¦-x¤pòáòñJÇ,½¿`Ìâ1ûJþÚU²ðtÊõ'ëÅÏ}4'%58éÅÌ¤iiÏ'½x6:éÉ¸&Äßûäú¤çfïßµlÃ¦­+¶Þ~9>«Rm¶¶vZ#ÿ5ËÁ¥µ-^e¿THÜ.¯dN¥é.fê®äè®d5_ÏR?ÈW'«R*ÏËç7<)&K_Ö&TfçVUUVTVäç¥%eÅ=M|ðôùãØ{g¯<~fßãøÇ)éIûîß¶{ËíûwÓs^ì:´-j{Ô¹+W&Ç\ºuöRôù»ïÞ~xûÔÅsN;såRÌ³+·¯í:°çþ×ïÞO»ó0:úÞ[÷oßú æiÌ­?xûøä¹cÇÎ»~ëÆÝnßyøäÞãè»ñ¯<yýâEFvzVNzvvZV¸ÍÈÍËÌËÎÈËLÏ{[ôäyùýç¥w^Ï½w357:%÷jjöå´´Ë©ÉRÒ.&åNN?z4ùÉÑäãIiGSv>={41uBÒ¦ó{ÇíKÛqGÂÍ#ñÏÖ>9²%aÿÑø±G¶ÄîßâXÜEOCÇ.x:s}ük÷Æîßðtþúg³.¼Øq3þzÔÓé_ì¼¿ÿbÜöÓO÷ÝxçÙ±m   9sjËÅKÏØûðDrÝ]Æ¦é|û¤ØöD¾ ÿ­·$ÅÞzy>¯~J,÷óQéûJÇª
9W¶äzé¦{%cK.%ßLÉ?¶û^öÅ'SòS²ó²òr
sK³ó3?¿qùöÙË·.¿~éØ×n<|÷ìä¹³+WïÛ´å|ÌãØ{îmÝvâÔ©1OW¬_7aò²Sg$$¥nÚ±sÕÊ-'N_}ò,!6îERJÆ½¸+×<}èDô¥kOî<x}ãÞÙ³·¢ïÄ>ñøÙO3ÒÓ³nÞ½}çyjzNIyaQIaqIafNNÌ³s·nßNºò çâ³kÏ²oÆçÜÏ½ó,÷N\ÞØ¼[±¹×ä^}sánö©èÌÓ¶I^µ;iö¦¤)[3ÆÈô¤èòÜ³CvgMº¿êiÁÕy[ÎçoÞ=#ºd]táî«En9]°æVáÛç·gE^-<|)ïÌ¡ì]gr_Ë¿¹3ëà¼ã§rnoÉ<µ=ãâ¾»;S,M¼´äùù±W>»½!öÙG±á÷bgÞyy÷Qèø]z:áÜ    çîN?óxÒÙÛÁgoÍ<}gÊéËó.ÞZráÚâWÃOzlÃó»ÎÆ%Ö*´mvÇ[Ù|ão   ùÿ=Xmm ¥tTÕ6~1yÑugOÆHW¿X·-®öbzõ­G¹% ùÙ¥Eûn&
_sôb\YQziYFYyVyENiev\Ò3/ïØwüÀ±Kg/Ý;~úÆã×/]½ð"áìùgÎß¿8H¼÷8þYBr~Q~JZÆèø§ÓJKËóÓÒrÓSrò+*J*ªKJKKJËÊ**Ë+ªÀmieeqUu©¤¶²®¾RR[V#)£ZRRQ]TR[Z_Tö<%!&>æòýsGnÜrsÝ'÷dFÌ$káìG³×ÌÞx:gëÙÜçrwÏÝs.wÿÙÜçòÏ;z¡àøå¢3W/^+¹z­øæí²ûK<*M¸_t·4)¦ôÅýÒô»¥·2¯d§OK¼z<9ñTjú¹ìâ³ùÕÓ¦×í|Q¶#©f[|MTBýÊØêÕ±î×EÞDÆ4ßlz¡<èªdæ9IÐùúÉ§Ç.y ü÷Ýùî.¶5ØÎ6äÙRòíîÆo×~½2û«9ß­ÎûtCå«K/Íû|Uá§2?_óÕòâoV~µ²ø³¥Y?¬Ë}¶îqÏZ[°Õñ¿®ÿ°?¡A®;wÍà ¨·'}2qÞÝÚ[µÇR+ïåWÜË-}S_]{úzÒÙèøk÷JÄÇ?Ix~÷aìÃÇOã_$%Ç'¼xñ"-5#-#'5·0³°$·¸$YPSXS\WX]\[Q]X^_UP]VWVøûKrÊ²ËsK²ò3ò
ÒsÀmf.ù9©iYÀÏ22²SÓ3R3²2S2Á3e¦gfefåææäæçI+¥ÕÒªªZI¤¶ªVµõµR0Ê$u`×ÔJ¤¥ÕÒâ*iIµ¬°B_^S.M/©ãE^EJY}b±ôInå¼ûÙU÷²*ïfÕ]+9[têaÕ¡[{.e¾s5K~üIåCqý÷+>«Ýõ@²óaí'Ò]O¶<miØþ¤iO:¾ñ¾vãcmTzc!*^ù@·2[.Ç>'ç§r!   ô´çìTË  Ï-ãmÃ¬C[?kûàIËZ¿Ò:"¶mpLÛ;Ñm?ßoÿ¨}Ìý¡ÍN°o0Réz=¨Aªmí,Û2¥zâ¼?®ø×Ú^Ã·|5ïjð©=q¥ûËÏdVÎ¨:Zr5³ønniLaÙ½¼²{Ùe1Y¥÷²c2g>ÊÊ{÷$#'63+>3¸ô¸ôôôô´çiÉ`¤ff¥fd¦eefä:@Î6²ssÀÈÊÉÉÎËÍdäçgççfåçe    ¹ùEE%Å`y+*--)¯,¯¬¬¨ªªª©®©­ÔÕJ¤´¶¶¡¾¶±¾®¡´¾¦^*©ÖÔ××Hj¤R´QÒÔXÓ$«Êkeô¼ªäÌÒÔÜ²ü²ú<IQyC½ZUÜQÔ]®Ê(QäV*3år¸¼   Ï-×åIù5H~µ±XJä×àU*NÚêT|½ÖÜ ·4 6©ÊT×l©Õ[F«±KmuÆJck¾µm+F:
àöôæÖ4C{²®ã¶ãisÛ]uÛMÇEeÛIeÇÆÖ­²¶¨¶Ðªö òÖ?
ZÀÛòcjËG    -ï>²¿qËÖû­ç9KSÞ',¾ûMî;¯MçzÒmæ¶u§sÕMmvÖIÖ,øíÿtÆRiC¬ø-|ÝÀ±ß±¡ÿ¯zý¶qúÖÒ«V>­=S{>§öPRõþåÇÊN&M)¾Vt1µøRZñå´ki¥WÓÊ£3*¯eT\É¬¼Y}9Kr5§îfNýÝüÇE

6=*?+UÆ+*êäjmºDS×× /hÔ4+p©U¥¤IÉt¨\)Úk&´0©C(=JPZ30Á $§'ùfÅ) MÂ`Ìgæx3ÃæÌj5[¬2Ù9ÎÎZhÞf2Û%½²¼åí4o¥M6ÖdcLv2£ãÀ¯XõEO[´I§DÊÉNsr[odkul©mf*4l¾-P°YML²¯cK¸»þfµùj9¦;VÂï+6í,¶®Í³ÌÏ¶ÌÈ´K·þjû>Éöi¢ýÝx{ïG-¾wm®7íNíÐ9tÜ°B»mÐV´Á­ã¡UÓrÆié´ÍCDsqÞ%Tïªs©þ
_×h³Ù:;«ÿ$X:.hÑÊs×}8.êí?6¾±ï÷M;}5%gØâoV½®M¬ÑnÍhÓO}ª%¥~c$ðCI²þbbiÙ:)§-¸ mVaÛI[¦ý¼í©ªý|CÇ
YÇ=eûCe{¼¶½n«ÄZ+Ö:¢¥jS65eÓ16±¡¬à¬$o¥À0iqÖ1[À Í3e2q6!,ßf3ejøD¹ÕÊ±<gæ9ÞÄ4³µFâB
Ó<Ïs×ª¸<
kâi¦¢Y*NÊÖØ,9Ó` ´©2Í0®0Mº¡¬k¦jµt®RQUàVAUÈÉrY!§ÊÈ&²¸LPÕT~#]ØHfÖÑiÂ`Köi%{¯½UÉ_)çÏ[vY6ØVåÙæçØ§e¶LÈ°KkÑ2(©åý·ÚûÄØîØ|¢mÎlÎ'¬Î­¢ý6ÑN³x³YÅÖq¢Õ¬h%Z;EEs¢£(D'¡v©v©zcjÖÀwÿ$XFþ#lÅk?°¡ÿð
oþ¾©ïË¿ :µðÈÏ©·Ü#s úI1xP¶¥_bûÛ/Úû¾hïÔÞ;©ýÍ^Im½Û>Èhý(³ePFË7Ù­?å¶ükoYÐ²¢Ô~°Úv¬ÆrªÖr´Æz®Æ]o¹#µ$ÈÍ2mÂ*Sg`º¥e­%©fÖ4Ü=F)¥i¦y²²¤%Á­§®VÐ2æé4%Wnà
4}¹)Ò1O_(dÊLT!Sf)Vp:ÑáTlPLi\x
æR{»FqZSFVè&=Õ £¤Ít½­Õ05]­¤jTDCW)©R9U"§5t|×È4ÒR6«N¯g$Ll5ó´»[Éß¨à¯rJMÇJÌ
M{¬ks,Ës­rmÁYö  -ÃÓí?¥Ù¿Jnßò¯göÞì>ÑV/ÖEøMtØæ´Ïæ´Ãê´Í&Úh­aD«ÑrÊi))TéÅ3ÅSUâ©JÑEï=jýçE±9KW[ùù´¨þÃ×ÿë÷}\üùÌó3£@ìu   /¼GÏ|ûØì}Í"¾`q½`ñ¸hq¹bu¶y]·zß°yÞ±yß±¾cé{ßòÑSÛ 8ë÷   ¶IÖI)Lë²lKT¾e±ùd¹ézµéÄÜÄKô\©Ñ±=S¡¥f4"lF«    ÀÝ5a ÅÐ´¡­,Ø ä$±÷õÜ­yG=7Wjù¹Ò6²Î>¢Á>µÎöÄ6TÒòu-´Â^mZiÛÐ`9£6-.æcd\¡²ð§05ÎNç_È%µ8s"Ï³M5è­FzQ2øêè:W3Õ¤cjÔ«RAËéR9]O'¹j ¨\)QO'Å&KØgÕìÃJîNw«Ât³Üt®Ô|¢Ô¼¯È´³Ðº¹À¶,×27Ëmafÿõ¢eÀ3ûl=îÙ}oÛÝ¯Å²Nµ8±öÚDÛ­N[L¢uÅZ-$DóQÑD¬M×¦j§©§)§Õ6#Ö^±PÛ°qõ¤Èe_Eýkøú7mê÷ãÒO§    Y·°¦÷âIùÌ¹2>*1»³º]²¸_°z\³ùÜ´yÝ´~c]e¯ÔäË§±öï¬¿¾°KµeÙäÚ6X÷O.WªøgR>]ÆUhÙ'ÙzC¡b:
¡èNqb0QUG°
¦mjëd¹ýç:ûåö¯*ìïHÚ?¬nû¸¶í#iû{uí×·.·}VÕò¡¤íÚö·+Z¿*¶e]cû<ÑöV^Ë{ù-_dZG[¯É¹ÓulA)òLW§çÀ¡$M1*!è3ç9W¥§u(©4Òr#Ýd õL±}\ÏÔi©®TQå
x*j¢    É¨¼*KÊ$ÕÒ/jäZ6®½_ÅÝ®änWñ7+ùKå¦%æ½EæíEÖ¨ËÒ\ëìlëôû¬?3[~Ì°Úòn|ëì=îY=`¹·:´ØöÚ¶Z\ËÖ±¢µ¼h#^Læbâp£((Îy: J%*®mF_°ØºuÃÌK¿õÖ(`ý,8éä ·½·¦vÝ3Ë%v|ä/ïðÐYÇeÛE«ûU7­[¶æ¥Ü´LËù2ódËOÖñiÖtÛ,Û@UålùZ)¦PeNñyJ¶L
×3M­Äµ`HI4mgi¦+Pö¼Ù¾«³\Óú¾¤õ£º_ëìßUÙ?¯kX×þN]û{µmoU·¿]ÓþAMû5mU·}XÞöAiÛ/å­¶ü+¿õí¬÷ãmæÚûg´¼ÕÚúmNËûÖ¯,¿äX6Y$0câHGi( ­án³oP%(``£¤ÂHqê9Y`jÙ%l¨º¥`Je-º¸*j óÖÒ5UÍÄT²@±¢+M+LJÍgJL@Æ*´É=Ë*ø ml¦}XfËà4ûç/ìoÅµô{j±»GÛ\®ZÏÛDÇmNíN»m¢m'àëy¬Õx%-r%
Å³aqAäjºJ¤
Y«6ÿy°(Þ±ccÄÅßÎ\÷ö_Þü=ê!Ë?p*hÙè_ß[]£Îòß>´<«¦Ç±Ðy«×%«ûe«÷M«çMË»1¶Õüä4ö»xëÍ*sD&ÿS%(Ã¶(Û¶2×²¥Ð|¸Ôt£¿_Ë?rY
>_ä8)Â(0ZÓ) ¤961`/6¦5Ø>´¾_ßö}í*ûÐrû-¿µü^nû½Â>³©e½Ì¾We»¨µ>ÒYR¦9Ïh*M9>Ï`ºSÏFdOË­[$Ö9åö_òZ>NoéØÒ+±5 ÑkûÝ;¶Õí¡½×ë4n_s¹î°RfB)d@IéqêB)W££4]Çj©T3÷*øj5S§a*\ÉÉ- ^t¶M®å@ºªbâjGUìÝr6º»\aGÝ    ±Í;,«smó³ma9¶É¶QößÒZ¤Ú?O´Éý±½ç»ç-«Ûø¬]|Ü&:Ë.XáFSI´­h    )¸a*5fêDÓ4âéjq°ºwX­Êð`Ûõ+Ö,6gý»c6½õ{TÿV¼7îøô¥QÐ[,/_ôT#ºfd}XE¿}sBuËê{ÃÒóµw­Ï}8ÃrLÃ­Ë¹iÉi¶È,ÛÚ|ªcÅ¦«|L
×ÀeËØb%[®iìÒ õ@âi²e×(ÌëZÞ­m¿¶ýiÛOöªZ¾(mùMÒ²AÞUcÕaei¦£:8²§Ú8²%[À-OÚ8ÒÎmf2YÊV¨¸ÕÎS­àÑ)Z²qrÓÁJóò|Ë dû§Ï¬î÷m^¬}Ùú>´zÇX?yjZOUv3ifDHôt5àtÏª-LÖëHëë´´DÍ:±TAg70Å2ªXÆ6Ñ/$Ì³jçAUÈ>­áWÅÝ¨0_>XÌ.6ï+6o+±Áº8Ç6+Û6!Ã:2Ý>4½ePrËGö÷bmý   `yß²¹]³ uÒ&:fwÚcqÚjm06òNx!¼/T¡¢h6ï:qP³xJ<E!Rö%y-Àâ8vë¨uW³ú½1ßü}cÿ¡+92yÑz§wùÌ-qYùqeG?"_µøD[¼oXúÞ±|øÐòA¬íG_ãÌ3²,sr¬rLSmK²-ò-;ÌGKM×*Í÷%¦¤F>[Á«J-Sk`Z´ R,CÛX:å*¬Ö¶¾%i(iû¼¾ýº¶AU-«ìGÕÖ\SLOå4ÑF[9àW$HÙ L×=¸ök3ñ4Ñyð´H©2` ¨¤ÔÀn/4·¾ûÐâm¼cò¿i]´^çdR¬1°7ë!_'KLVÚH8_¯£dz²QØ¢Ëåä:æa=W,§
Ô:0Xpp«¹;,þR¶ÔäP,ÓÖËº\ë²\[hm\¦ýÏtû©öo[&Øß³÷y`ó»o÷¾is¹bs>g·ÛE»lXLÅ9°@Ik>.m%iOUNVúNªTLÿ<X<Ïmßµió¶õc#W¾?nCÿß¢ú
Y9`ì)K£\Þï¹ Ìw«bà=îÍÛëe³×
```

Comment: What is the URL to the image file?

Comment: I don't have direct access to the image file. I get the image stream from an API.

Comment: What is the URL to the API? Why is the response text?

Comment: @guest271314. - The API url looks like this https://[server]/api/image/thumb. It's not public accessible API

Comment: Have you tried the code at the Answer?

Comment: guest271314 - I am using axios to call API. But the answer looks like it uses 'Fetch'.

Comment: That should not matter. You should be able to specify the response type using `XMLHttpRequest`. Does axios use `XMLHttpRequest` or `Fetch` to make requests? Does the documentation for axios provide options to set the response type?

Comment: @guest271314 - I get response.blob is not a function

Comment: Can you post a link to the axios documentation?

Comment: @guest271314 - https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/blame/master/README.md#L281, e.g., `axios({
  method:'get',
  url:'<URL>',
  responseType:'blob'
})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163985/discussion-between-thangakumar-d-and-guest271314).

Comment: @guest271314- Thankyou. Once I mentioned 'responseType:'blob' I got valid blob object. Thank you so much!

Comment: FYI: GraphicsMagick (gm) is not the same as Imagemagick.

Comment: @fmw42- Thanks for the information ! I have corrected my question.